# How do i solve this circuit with Thevenin's?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, electrical

[image]

I am not sure how to place my voltage source after i combine the 2 parallel resistors R1 and R2. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method1 (specific method for voltage divider):
After you simplified the parralel resistors \$R_{23} = R_2 || R_3\$ you got a voltage source with voltage divider formed by \$R_{23}\$ and \$R_1\$.

The Thevenin Equivalent of a voltage source \$V_{src}\$ with voltage divider is a Thevenin source with \$V_{th}=V_{src}\frac{R_{23}}{R_1+R_{23}}\$ and \$R_{th}= R_1 || R_{23}\$

Method2 (general method that works always):
If you don't know this shortcut above: do what you should have learned in the lessons:

- find open circuit voltage \$V_{oc}\$ between a and b
- find short circuit current \$I_{sc}\$ between a and b
- use both results to derive \$V_{th}=V_{oc}\$ and \$R_{th}=\frac{V_{oc}}{I_{sc}}\$.

Answer (score 0):

First, r2//r3 so you find the equivalent resistance Req1. Then you see that R1 and Req1 are in series so you find the equivalent resistance between r1 an Req1 and i think it's good. you have your equivalent schema.

Comment: The OP asked about using Thevenin.

Comment: i should have said it was the beginning of method to find equivalent schema. After you just had to  as @curd said. 
Sorry i wasn't explicit.